# Programmatically divide screen into N-rectangles with pygame

Tags: python, pandas, pygame

I have a stream of input data from multiple "channels" and I want to represent each channel's data stream within a section of the screen using `pygame`.

The streaming data is captured in a `pandas` data.frame and summarized every few seconds. Right now I've prototyped this using only the first channel of data and fullscreen mode in pygame (i.e., `scr = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)`).

The way I'm trying to divide up the screen is [a lot like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403675/how-to-create-a-4-way-split-screen-in-pygame) but instead of having a fixed number of sub-screens to create, I'm hoping to reference the number of columns in the pandas data.frame to divide up the screen programmatically.

Should this be done using `Surface` and some sort of loop? Just looking for some guidance as this type of programming is new to me. I've seen something vaguely similar with geographic data (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144869/divide-a-rectangle-into-n-equal-subrectangles)) but the context of working with displays and `pygame` is enough to make me a bit uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would indeed work with `pygame.Surface`s and a loop.

I took a primer on pygame (my go to is: https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/) and added how I would implement multiple sub_screens (or `surf`s in my script below). I hope my code and comments are clear enough to get what's going on, otherwise just ask!

For now I just fill the sub-screens with random colors, but you can blit anything you want on the sub-screens (in or outside the while-loop), as they are just good old pygame.Surfaces.

```
import pygame
import random

# init pygame
pygame.init()

# set up parameters
n_rows = 5
n_cols = 3

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 500

# Create a dict with the row and column as key,
# and a tuple containing a Surface and its topleft coordinate as value
surf_width = round(screen_width / n_cols)
surf_height = round(screen_height / n_rows)

surfaces_dct = {}
for row in range(n_rows):
    for col in range(n_cols):

        # create a surface with given size
        surf = pygame.Surface(size=(surf_width, surf_height))
        # get its top left coordinate
        top_left = (col*surf_width, row*surf_height)

        # put it in the dict as a tuple
        surfaces_dct[(row, col)] = (surf, top_left)


# Here you can blit anything to each surface/sub-screen (defined by it's row and column):
for key, value in surfaces_dct.items():
    # unpack the key, value pairs
    (row, col) = key
    (surf, top_left) = value
    
    # I just fill each surface with a random color for demonstration
    (r, g, b) = [random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(3)]
    surf.fill((r, g, b))


# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:

    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # You can also run this for-loop here, inside the main while-loop
    # to dynamically change what's on each surf
    # as you see you can also unpack the key and value like this
    for (row, col), (surf, top_left) in surfaces_dct.items():
        # I'll leave it blank here
        pass


    # Finally place(/blit) the surfaces on the screen given
    screen.blits(list(surfaces_dct.values()))

    #### the above is the same as doing:
    # for surf, top_left in surfaces_dct.values():
    #     screen.blit(surf, top_left)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.update()
```